# php recursive string parsing

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, recursion

```
{‘a’: True, ‘b’: ‘c’, 'd':{'e': 'f', 'g': h}}
```

how can i parse this string to array(with key,value) in php.

```
Array(
   a -> True
   b -> 'c'
   d -> Array(
     e -> f
     g -> h
   )
)
```

This is not standard json. I can not use json_decode.

---

I tried json_decode.

Sample data :

> `{'timestamp': '0.', 'class': 'vbd_metrics', 'snapshot': {'io_read_kbs': 0.0, 'last_updated': <DateTime u'19700101T00:00:00Z' at 8b7cacc>, 'uuid': '7b3e71e5-b43a-2c5d-d582-09302901c7fe', 'other_config': {}, 'io_write_kbs': 0.0}, 'operation': 'mod', 'ref': 'OpaqueRef:1c934395-abe1-36a8-9926-20c5e03c1799', 'id': '895794'}`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please edit your question to show some code you already have.

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This looks like a Python dict, can't you export it to JSON with Python and then parse it with `json_decode`?

Comment: "This is not standart json": in this case, use regex to transform it to standart json.

Comment: What you want is called lexical analysis. Start with a Google search on that.

Comment: i tried json_decode. Sample data : {'timestamp': '0.', 'class': 'vbd_metrics', 'snapshot': {'io_read_kbs': 0.0, 'last_updated': <DateTime u'19700101T00:00:00Z' at 8b7cacc>, 'uuid': '7b3e71e5-b43a-2c5d-d582-09302901c7fe', 'other_config': {}, 'io_write_kbs': 0.0}, 'operation': 'mod', 'ref': 'OpaqueRef:1c934395-abe1-36a8-9926-20c5e03c1799', 'id': '895794'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as a starting point:

```
 $data="{'timestamp': '0.', 'class': 'vbd_metrics', 'snapshot': {'io_read_kbs': 0.0, 'last_updated': <DateTime u'19700101T00:00:00Z' at 8b7cacc>, 'uuid': '7b3e71e5-b43a-2c5d-d582-09302901c7fe', 'other_config': {}, 'io_write_kbs': 0.0}, 'operation': 'mod', 'ref': 'OpaqueRef:1c934395-abe1-36a8-9926-20c5e03c1799', 'id': '895794'}";

  Var_dump(eval('return '.join('',array_slice(array_map(
  function($v){
      if(is_array($v)){
        $v[1]=str_replace('’','"',$v[1]);
        $v[1]=str_replace('‘','"',$v[1]);
        $v[1]=trim($v[1]);
        if(!empty($v[1])&&$v[1][0]==='<'&&$v[1][strlen($v[1])-1]==='>')
            $v[1]=substr($v[1],1,-1);
        $v=$v[1];
    }else{
        if($v==='{') $v='[';
        if($v==='}') $v=']';
        if($v===':') $v='=>';
        if($v==='<') $v='"';
        if($v==='>') $v='"';
    }

    return $v;

},token_get_all('<?php '.$data.' ?>')),1,-1)).';'));
```

The output is:

```
array(6) {
  ["timestamp"]=>
  string(2) "0."
  ["class"]=>
  string(11) "vbd_metrics"
  ["snapshot"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["io_read_kbs"]=>
    float(0)
    ["last_updated"]=>
    string(38) "DateTimeu'19700101T00:00:00Z'at8b7cacc"
    ["uuid"]=>
    string(36) "7b3e71e5-b43a-2c5d-d582-09302901c7fe"
    ["other_config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["io_write_kbs"]=>
    float(0)
  }
  ["operation"]=>
  string(3) "mod"
  ["ref"]=>
  string(46) "OpaqueRef:1c934395-abe1-36a8-9926-20c5e03c1799"
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) "895794"
}
```

Basically this code simulate the parsing of a valid PHP code .This then allow to replace easily some characters with str_replace.Finally we remove the Start tag and the end tag.We join the array to get a string and then use eval to return it as a valid array.Dirty but functional.

Comment: you test it wrong way.The only thing i change in your sample is the last h by 'h'.The only error could be  use of undefined constant h assumed h so but it will work although this error...